# Show Open/Closed for a Set and two continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Let f, g : X → R be two continuous functions defined on a metric space X.
(i) Show that the set U = {x ∈ X : f(x) > g(x)} is open in X.
(ii) Show that the set F = {x ∈ X : f(x) ≥ g(x)} is closed in X.
(iii) Show that the set G = {x ∈ X : f(x) = g(x)} is closed in X.

I am trying to use the definition of continuity of a function, but I get stuck after that. Can someone help and explain the process of solving these 3 sub problems?

Comment: What's your definition of continuity say? Part i can be slightly simplified by saying $h = f - g$; then $h$ is continuous as well, $U$ is the set where $h > 0$. That is to say, $U = h^{-1}( (0, \infty) )$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To i)**

Assume that $x_0\in U,$ that is, $f(x_0)-g(x_0)=2\epsilon>0.$ Now, since $f,g$ are continuous at $x_0$ there exists

$$\delta_1>0 : d(x,x_0)<\delta_1 \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon \implies f(x)>f(x_0)-\epsilon,$$

$$\delta_2>0 : d(x,x_0)<\delta_2 \implies |g(x)-g(x_0)|<\epsilon \implies g(x)<g(x_0)+\epsilon.$$

Thus,

$$d(x,x_0)<\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}\implies g(x)<g(x_0)+\epsilon=f(x_0)-\epsilon<f(x).$$

That is, $B(x_0,r)\subset U.$

**To ii)**

Show that $F^c$ is open using $i).$

**To iii)**

Show that $G^c$ is open using $i)$ and the intersection of two adequate sets.